# Could not set edited text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I wanted to implement inline editing but is facing a problem. When i click the text, a textfield appears and when i fill the text and hit enter or click somewhere, the filled text is not set. What mistake i have done?

**Code**

```
export default class InlineEditing extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      edit: false,
      text: 'Click here to name your device'
    };
  }

  handleDeviceName = () => { this.setState({ edit: true })};

  addDeviceName = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper>
        <div
          onClick={this.handleDeviceName}
        >
          {this.state.edit ?
            <TextField
              name = "device_name"
              onClick={this.addDeviceName}
            /> :
            this.state.text
          }
        </div>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `e.target` is the input field when you call `addDeviceName()`?

Comment: I am getting the value. The problem is only the text is not set. Even after clicking or hitting enter, textbox does not disappear.

Comment: `addDeviceName` will be called as soon as the user clicks on the textfield, and the current text of the field will be set in state. You need to change `onClick` to some thing like `onChange` or `onBlur`

PS: try and let me know if it worked.

Comment: onBlur worked for me. Thanks. Can you please post it as answer with that explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the function `addDeviceName` will be called as soon as the user clicks on the textfield, and the current text of the field will be set in state.
You need to change `onClick` event to some thing like `onChange` or `onBlur`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{this.state.edit ?
      <TextField
          name = "device_name"
          onChange={this._addDeviceName.bind(this)}
      /> :
      this.state.text
 }

_addDeviceName(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        this.setState({edit: false});
    }else{
       this.setState({text:e.target.value});  
    }  
 }
```

Comment: I am using arrow function so there is no need of binding.

Comment: I am getting the value. Problem is not with binding.

Comment: i think check the key code if user press the enter key then hide it otherwise allow him to change the text, it should work.